# Spark RDD Persistence and Partitions

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd, bigdata

When a certain RDD is created in Spark for example:

```
lines = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

And then a transformation is called on this RDD:

```
pythonLines = lines.filter(lambda line: "Python" in line)
```

If you call an action on this transformed Filter RDD (such as `pythonlines.first`) what does it mean when they say `an RDD will be recomputed ones again each time you run an action on them`? I thought the original RDD that you created using the textFile method is not persisted after you called the `filter` transformation on that original RDD. So will it just recompute the most recent transformed RDD, where in this case it is the RDD I made using the filter transformation? I don't really see why that would be necessary if my assumption is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spark, RDDs are *lazily* evaluated. This means if you simply write

```
lines = sc.textFile("README.md").map(xxx)
```

Your program will exit without reading the file since you never used the result. If you write something like:

```
linesLength = sc.textFile("README.md").map(line => line.split(" ").length)
sumLinesLength = linesLength.reduce(_ + _) // <-- scala way
maxLineLength = linesLength.max()
```

The computations needed to have `lineLength` will be made *twice*, since you are reusing it in two different places. To avoid that, you should persist your resulting RDD before using it in two different ways

```
linesLength = sc.textFile("README.md").map(line => line.split(" ").length)
linesLength.persist()
// ...
```

You can also take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence. Hope my explanation isn't too confused!

Comment: Ohh, so in your second example when you have those three lines after you call the last line: `maxLineLength = linesLength.max()` the `linesLength` RDD will be gone since you are done using it. So if you want to use the linesLength RDD in multiple places in your program you should persist it so you have access to it even after you are done using the `linesLength RDD`. Correct?

Comment: Basically when you have an intermediate result (such as lineLength in my example) that you are reusing several times, you should persist() it otherwise spark will compute it several times as well. A RDD is not data, it is "a list of computations". So if you write `linesLength.max()`, Spark will not understand « *the maximum of what you computed earlier* » but « *the maximum of the RDD I can get by reading this file and executing the map* »

Comment: Ok now I see what it means by the RDD will recomputed overtime. Thanks for the clarification!